# How does Double.intValue() work?

Tags: java, integer, double

This code

```
Double dbl = 254.9999999999999;
Integer integ = dbl.intValue();
System.out.println(integ);
```

shows 254, but one "9" more

```
Double dbl = 254.99999999999999;
Integer integ = dbl.intValue();
System.out.println(integ);
```

and it is already 255..
Why?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To know the exact value of your double, you can use a BigDecimal:

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(254.9999999999999));
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(254.99999999999999));
```

prints:

```
254.9999999999998863131622783839702606201171875
255
```

So this is simply due to (limitations of) double precision...

Comment: Which, when thinking about it, is not that surprising. A double can at most store only 18446744073709551616 different values. There's a lot more numbers than that even between 0.0 and 1.0. So, since a double cannot store every possible numbers, it stores approximations for the ones it cannot store precisely. e.g. the nearest double aproximation of 254.99999999999999 is 255, while the nearest approximation to 254.9999999999999 is 254.9999999999998863131622783839702606201171875

Comment: @nos In more formal terms, the nearest `double` value to the number `254.99999999999999` is `255.0`.

Answer (score 13):

```
System.out.println(254.9999999999999 == 255.0);
System.out.println(254.99999999999999 == 255.0);
```

prints

```
false
true
```

That should give you a hint. The `double` type can represent up to 16 significant digits, and your literal has 17. Therefore the `double` value nearest to the second decimal literal is `255.0`.

For the second line of code, Eclipse actually issues a warning:

> Comparing identical expressions

because it is already the *compiler* which is aware of the fact that these are just two literals for the exact same `double` value.

Comment: println does some rounding too (admittedly to another double which is supposed to be equivalent) - so I'm not sure you can draw a definite conclusion from that experiment.

Comment: @assylias It does the rounding which is sane for a `double`---eliminating the spurious decimal digits which stem from the decimal/binary mismatch and do not represent actual precision. Your code makes those extra digits show.

Comment: Aren't there any instances where a double with decimal would print as a number without any decimals? (I suppose not actually)...

Comment: @assylias I've realized it's actually [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString(double)): "There must be at least one digit to represent the fractional part, and beyond that as many, but only as many, more digits as are needed to uniquely distinguish the argument value from adjacent values of type double." So actually, printing with `println` is proof enough.

Answer (score 4):

A double is a 64-bit binary floating point representation of a number. Binary floating point numbers cannot exactly represent most decimal fractions. They can exactly represent 1/2, 1/4, 1/64+1/32 etc but they cannot exactly represent 0.9 or 0.1. Furthermore their precision is limited.

In your case, 254.99999999999999 has exactly the same representation as 255.0 internally. You can see this by checking a hexadecimal version of the binary fraction, using the `Double.toHexString` method. Because 254.99999999999999 is already equal to 255.0, when you cut off the fractional part by casting it to a 32-bit integer, you end up with 255.

```
System.out.println("a: " + Double.toHexString(254.99999999999999d));
System.out.println("b: " + Double.toHexString(255d));
```

**Output**

```
a: 0x1.fep7
b: 0x1.fep7
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer is rather simple. The decimal number you wrote in your code with one 9 more is closer to the double which represents exactly 255 than any other double. So, the double that is used in the compilation is exactly equal to 255. While the decimal number with one 9 less is optimally represented with a double I show below. This means that it lies closer to that specific double than any other double.

Check out this demo: http://ideone.com/hSqJTJ

This is the output:

```
Original double: 254.9999999999999
Cast to int: 254
Exact double: 254.9999999999998863131622783839702606201171875

Original double: 255.0
Cast to int: 255
Exact double: 255
```

Answer (score 3):

double binary format is sign (1) + exponent (11) + fraction (53). Binary form for `254.9999999999999` and `254.99999999999999` is

```
0 10000000110 1111110111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
0 10000000110 1111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

we can get it as `Long.toString(dbl.doubleToLongBits(dbl), 2);`

integer part is

```
1111110
1111111
```

leading 1 bit is omitted so actual integer values are

```
11111110 - 254
11111111 - 255
```

note that cast double to integer is done not by rounding but truncation

Comment: I make a point of adding 0.5 to any floating point number before casting to int.  This tends to give the answer you'd expect more often.